# Add hyperlink to excel sheet closedxml

Tags: c#, excel, hyperlink, closedxml

I am converting a data table to excel which is working fine. I have 4 columns in data table. Column1 and Column2 are simple text. Column3 and Column4 are hyperlink url and display text. all 4 columns are exported as it is in excel with below code :

```
        string fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filename"];
        string sheetName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {               
            var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(ptDataTable, sheetName);

            ws.Style.Font.FontName = "Arial";
            ws.Style.Font.FontSize = 10;
            ws.Style.Alignment.WrapText = true;
            ws.FirstRow().Style.Alignment.SetWrapText(true);

            ws.Style.Alignment.SetWrapText(true);
            ws.Style.Alignment.SetShrinkToFit(true);
            ws.Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Top;
            ws.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Left;
            ws.Rows().AdjustToContents();
            ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();

            ws.Rows(2,200).Style.Fill.SetBackgroundColor((XLColor.Transparent));
            ws.Columns(9, 10).Width = 50.0;
            ws.Range("A2:J200").Style.Border.SetInsideBorder(XLBorderStyleValues.Thin);
            ws.Range("A2:J200").Style.Border.SetOutsideBorder(XLBorderStyleValues.Thin);


            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(stream);
                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
            }
        }
```

I want to create hyperlink with column3(url) and column4(display text) and this hyperlink will be 3 column in exported excel.

Any idea!

Answer (score 9):

You will have to loop through the cells and add the hyperlinks manually:

```
ws.Cell(rowNumber, columnNumber).Hyperlink = new XLHyperlink(@"http://www.yahoo.com");
```

You can find more info about hyperlinks in ClosedXML at https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Using-Hyperlinks

Comment: I donot want to loop through cells as it will be time consuming

Comment: If you want to do it with ClosedXML, that is your only option.

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, your code is using the ClosedXML library, not the OpenXMLSDK.

There are two ways to add hyperlinks in OpenXMLSDK:

- writing a `=HYPERLINK` formula into cells

  ```
  Cell cell = new Cell()
  {
    CellReference = "A3",
    DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number),
    CellFormula = "=HYPERLINK(yourlinklocationcellhere, yourfriendlyhyperlinknamehere)"
  };
  ```
- creating Hyperlink objects in the Worksheets.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.hyperlink?view=openxml-2.8.1

Answer (score 2):

`Francois Botha`'s answer works, but it is pretty slow for a large number of hyperlinks (in the thousands, as each hyperlink generation takes up a couple of milliseconds to generate).

A good alternative is to generate the hyperlink using a formula:

```
cell.FormulaA1 = $"=HYPERLINK(\"{url}\", \"{text}\")";
```

A function using this approach that also ensures valid hyperlink values can be found on [Codidact](https://software.codidact.com/posts/286693/286694#answer-286694).

Comment: A downside to this approach, is that you lose the option for Tooltips

Answer (score 1):

Further to @Francois Botha's earlier solution, it need not take much code.

e.g. in VB.NET, I just used the following code to convert a string column containing URLs(already populated from my SQLServer database query's resultant DataTable) to clickable links:

```
    For Each wsrow In wc.Rows
        'Was: wsrow.Cell("G").Hyperlink = New XLHyperlink(wsrow.Cell("G"))
         wsrow.Cell("G").SetHyperlink(New XLHyperlink(url))
    Next
```

**UPDATE:  No, that appeared to work - highlighted URL - but the link content is empty :(
Works a treat.  FYI I am using quite an old version of OpenXML, 0.68.1.***

**I tried upgrading ClosedXML yesterday but it broke some essential existing code and the image display capability did not work for me - I was too short of time to mess about with it further.*

Comment: Tried updating closed XML.  Changing the middle line above as shown below allows it to build (but not fully tested yet):  wsrow.Cell("H").SetHyperlink(New XLHyperlink(url2))